# Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, path, prettyphoto

SO my file hierarchy that is the same on my desktop as it is in my web-host file manager

1- This is my iframe from my code editing program (Adobe Edge Code) correctly working when I throw the page up in Google Chrome]

2- And this is my iframe not working when I have the page hosted in my web-hosts file manager.

1: https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/leyton/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-20%20at%203.51.37%20PM.png?uniq=-n0ztwi

2: http://leytonelizabeth.com/photography.html

I don't know anything about Javascript and definitely nothing about JQuery. All I know is that I have a code that correctly displays my website when I preview it on Google Chrome.

When I put all my files in the exact same hierarchical order in my web-hosting site's file manager, I navigate to it and it doesn't work.

Why does it point to the files and paths correctly when it's coming from my desktop and not when it's coming from Webhostinghub.com?? I transferred them over in exactly the same order. The paths are correct. So it must be something with jQuery. Can anyone give me some advice or things to try in order to get the iframe to display my photos?

Is it perhaps because there are several Core Scripts being referenced at the top of my photography.html page? do I need to update/download each version? Do viewers looking at my site need to go through all that too then just to potentially see the photos in my iframe? As you can see in the pic of the photo that properly works in the iframe, it points to the prettyPhoto jQuery and its respected gallery, not some other url..

I have NO IDEA what to do about this. Please help!!!

These are the scripts at the top of all my html5 documents/pages:

```
`<!-- Cufon Scripts -->
    <script src="js/libs/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/fonts/mank-sans.cufonfonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/fonts/Yanone_Kaffeesatz_Regular_400.font.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <script src="js/royale-cufon.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- Core Scripts -->
    <script src="js/libs/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/mdetect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <script src="js/royale.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bg Image Script -->
    <script src="js/royale-bg-image.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Added for Lightbox Script -->
    <script src="js/libs/jquery.pretty-photo.min.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Setup Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">`
```

Comment: Perhaps a screen shot of the pic file structure and the Web host file structure might be handy

Comment: why are some images from thumbs3 are getting loaded and some are not found? for e.g. tea_thumbs is loaded but some others are not. please check your folder and file structure again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Lots of your 'thumb' folders are empty.

2 The "big-sized" picture of teacup (the only thumb picture i can see) is  referred as "img/portfolio/theaccident/tea.jpg", but the real file path is "img/portfolio/theaccident/Tea.jpg" (the capital letter matters)

So the problem is not in the scripts, It's in your export settings or your host defaults.

UPD:

3 Some links from your 'thumbless' pictures are pointing to correct 'big-sized' pictures (their first letters are not capitalized).

You definetely did something wrong when moving everything from desktop to host.